# RHEL 6.5 Command Line Tool for Sybase ASE 15

Tags: sql, command-line, sap-ase, rhel6

I need to access a Sybase ASE Database from a RHEL 6.5 machine in order to test some SQL Queries there.

Already tried sqlplus64, which gives me a

```
ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet
```

for

```
$ sqlplus64 <username>/<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_schema_name>
```

which makes sense for me, since it's an Oracle Tool and propably expects an Oracle Database.

I read about using isql but I don't know how to install it on RHEL 6.5?!

Any suggestion for other tools or is it possible to use sqlplus64 somehow?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the Sybase isql command line utility?

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19165/scriptable-command-line-access-to-sql-server-from-linux  (it's for SQL Server, but as Sybase and SQL Server have the same protocol the same tools might work)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct sqlplus64 will not connect to a Sybase database instance.

If the Sybase ASE instance was installed correctly, isql should be found in $SYBASE/$SYBASE_OCS/bin

To start the tool:

```
isql -U <user name> -S <sybase instance name>
```

you will be prompted for the password

An alternative command line tool is sqsh, which can be downloaded from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqsh/files/

Sqsh can be started as follows:

```
sqsh -U <user name> -S <sybase instance name>
```